# Tk button throws error: Takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) on call

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

My issue within my code is that when I click the submit button on my `topLevel()` window it gives me the error listed in the title. If I attempt to put `top.submit_button` it throws the error that `submit_button` is not part of `topLevel()`. I have searched all over stackoverflow but haven't found a problem similar to this one. I am new to Python GUI programming and would really appreciate the help.

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.KTitle = tk.Label(self, text="Login ")
        self.KTitle.grid(row=7,column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.KUsername = tk.Label(self, text="Username: ")
        self.KUsername.grid(row=8,column=0, sticky=E)
        self.KPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ")
        self.KPassword.grid(row=9,column=0, sticky=E)
        self.KUEntry = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.KUEntry.grid(row=8,column=1, sticky=E)
        self.KUPass = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.KUPass.grid(row=9,column=1, sticky=E)

        self.KUSubmit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.KUSubmit.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.KTitle = tk.Label(self, text=" or ")
        self.KTitle.grid(row=11,column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.KUSubmit = tk.Button(self, text="Create an Account", command=self.create_button)
        self.KUSubmit.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def create_button(self):

        top = Toplevel()

        top.TitleHead = tk.Label(top, text="Create an Account ")
        top.TitleHead.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan=3)

        #userInput
        top.f_name = tk.Label(top, text="First Name: ")
        top.f_name.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry1.grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.l_name = tk.Label(top, text="Last Name: ")
        top.l_name.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry2 = tk.Entry(top,width=15)
        top.Entry2.grid(row=2,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.username = tk.Label(top, text="Username: ")
        top.username.grid(row=3,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry3 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry3.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.Ptoken = tk.Label(top, text="Password: ")
        top.Ptoken.grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry4 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry4.grid(row=4,column=3, sticky=W)

        top.Submit = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", command=submit_button)
        top.Submit.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

    def submit_button(top):

        x = top.Entry4.get()
        salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
        hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(x + salt).hexdigest()

        add = ("INSERT INTO User "
               "(ID, username, f_name, l_name, salt, PashHash) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

        ID = int(0)
        username = top.Entry3.get()
        f_name = top.Entry1.get()
        l_name = top.Entry2.get()
        salt = salt
        PashHash = hashed_password

        data = (ID , top.username , top.f_name , top.l_name, salt, PashHash)

        cursor.execute(add, data)
        cnx.commit()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `def submit_button(top)` should be `def submit_button(self, top)` if it's part of the class

Comment: Please show the complete error.

Comment: Which `Button`? Why to you assign two different ones to `self.KUSubmit`?

Comment: @depperm: What will be the source of the `top` argument (whether your suggested change is put in or not)?

Comment: The create_button is the button on the first (primary) window that is created on launch. The submit_button is the button at the bottom of the topLevel() window. The error the compiler gives me is "create_button takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" when I try to press the submit button which is the submit_button function. Here is the error, copy and pasted. and the double KUSubmit is a copy and paste error.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: submit_button() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Please don't post stack traces or code in the comments section. You can edit your question by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43593249/edit) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are setting up the callback function for the (second) `KUSubmit` button. First of all, since it's a method of the `SampleApp` class, it will automatically receive a `self` argument.

Second is passing an argument to it. Which, although that can be done, in this case it's easier to just save the value in a `self.top` attribute, and retrieve it from there in the method via its automatic `self` argument.

I'm made changes along these lines to your code show below. See the lines with `# CHANGED` comments for specifics.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.KTitle = tk.Label(self, text="Login ")
        self.KTitle.grid(row=7,column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.KUsername = tk.Label(self, text="Username: ")
        self.KUsername.grid(row=8,column=0, sticky=E)
        self.KPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ")
        self.KPassword.grid(row=9,column=0, sticky=E)
        self.KUEntry = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.KUEntry.grid(row=8,column=1, sticky=E)
        self.KUPass = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
        self.KUPass.grid(row=9,column=1, sticky=E)

        self.KUSubmit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.KUSubmit.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.KTitle = tk.Label(self, text=" or ")
        self.KTitle.grid(row=11,column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.KUSubmit = tk.Button(self, text="Create an Account",
                                  command=self.create_button)
        self.KUSubmit.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def create_button(self):

        self.top = top = Toplevel()  # CHANGED

        top.TitleHead = tk.Label(top, text="Create an Account ")
        top.TitleHead.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan=3)

        #userInput
        top.f_name = tk.Label(top, text="First Name: ")
        top.f_name.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry1.grid(row=1,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.l_name = tk.Label(top, text="Last Name: ")
        top.l_name.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry2 = tk.Entry(top,width=15)
        top.Entry2.grid(row=2,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.username = tk.Label(top, text="Username: ")
        top.username.grid(row=3,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry3 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry3.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky=W)
        top.Ptoken = tk.Label(top, text="Password: ")
        top.Ptoken.grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=W)
        top.Entry4 = tk.Entry(top, width=15)
        top.Entry4.grid(row=4,column=3, sticky=W)

        top.Submit = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", command=self.submit_button)
        top.Submit.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

    def submit_button(self):  # CHANGED

        x = self.top.Entry4.get()  # CHANGED
        salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
        hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(x + salt).hexdigest()

        add = ("INSERT INTO User "
               "(ID, username, f_name, l_name, salt, PashHash) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

        ID = int(0)
        username = top.Entry3.get()
        f_name = top.Entry1.get()
        l_name = top.Entry2.get()
        salt = salt
        PashHash = hashed_password

        data = (ID , top.username , top.f_name , top.l_name, salt, PashHash)

        cursor.execute(add, data)
        cnx.commit()

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Copy and pasting your code gave me this error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./Uninote.py", line 123, in create_button
    top.Submit = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", command=self.submit_button)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: submit_button

Comment: It doesn't when I run it, but there may be other issues with the code as I didn't try every possible interaction. What where you doing when the error occurred?

Comment: From the Traceback it looks like `submit_button` isn't being recognized as a method, so execution stops. That much is definitely happening in what little testing I did, so I don't know what the issue could be if you copied the code in my answer without any changes.

Comment: Your method does work (thank for that by the way). The issue was with my indention. So the code compiles and runs but when I click the submit button in the topLevel() window, it gives me this: (next comment)

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./Uninote.py", line 128, in submit_button
    x = self.top.Entry4.get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: top

Comment: It's difficult to read Tracebacks pasted into a comments like that. Don't do it again because this is my last response. Anyway, it looks like tkinter can't find an attribute named `top`. An attribute by that name is assigned to in the function `create_button()` in the first line: `self.top = top = Toplevel()  # CHANGED`. Make sure you have that in the code you're running.

Comment: Thank you. Im apologize for the issues.